# Sentence completion using a Clause

Tags: clauses, sentence-choice, subordinate-clauses

I've got a sentence

**Good people get up ______**

Could I use
*"Early in the morning "* ? Is it a Clause?

The answer given is 
*"when the sun rises"?*

---

Please tell which one is correct or both?
Also, please explain why.
Thank you.

Comment: "Early in the morning" is an adverbial phrase, or in general it's a phrase. However, "when the sun rises" is an adverbial clause, or in general it's a clause. I think both are correct grammatically.

Comment: "Early in the morning" is not a clause because it does not contain a verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clause should contain subject and predicate, either explicit or implicit.

> He wants *[to go to the circus]*.

*TO*-infinitive clause - *to go to the circus*. It's a clause because it contains an implicit Subject - *he*, Predicator - *go* and Complement - *to the circus*. Subject - *he* and Predicate - *go to the circus*. That *to* can be regarded as a subordinator.

> It's possible [for him to jump over the wall].

Here the *TO*-infinitive clause has an explicit subject -*him*.

But your *early in the morning* is not a clause. It lacks a subject and a predicator. It, however, can be analyzed as a phrase.

*early* is an adverb and it's a head-word. And it takes a Preposition Phrase (PP) as a post-modifier. so *early in the morning* is an Adverb Phrase (AdvP).

In your sentence -

> Good people get up *[early in the morning]*.

The AdvP acts as a temporal adjunct. You can also use a clause there instead of that AdvP. A good choice is, as Cardinal suggested in his comment, ***when the sun rises***.